# Returning a single value from JSON

Tags: sql, json

I am using an MDM that has a custom reporting feature that allows for some SQL.  I'd like to try and get a list of SIM card ICCID numbers, but it is returned in a JSON string with other device information.

Running:

```sql
SELECT DeviceDetails
FROM Device
```

Returns (no whitespace, formatted for readability):

```json
{
    "BadgeNumber": 0,
    "DeviceLocale": "en-US",
    "ICCID": "0000000000000004720",
    "InstalledPoliciesSignedBy": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX1690F",
    "AvailableDeviceCapacity": 00000000080,
    "OSSdkVersion": 24,
    "ModemFirmwareVersion": "angler-03.72",
    "DeviceCapacity": 00000000184,
    "Product": "Nexus 6P/angler",
    "WiFiMAC": "02:00:00:00:00:00"
}
```

I don't know what flavor of SQL it's running unfortunately. Any idea on how I can just return the ICCID value?

---

Edit: found this in the reporting docs:

> Admin Portal uses a subset of SQL-92 that only supports SELECT statements. SQL commands that change database values are not valid (CREATE, ALTER, DELETE, DROP, INSERT, SELECT INTO, TRUNCATE, UPDATE, and so forth).

Comment: Which flavor of SQL is this?  MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle?

Comment: Unknown flavor unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

**MySQL:**

```
SELECT DeviceDetails->"$.ICCID" as ICCID
FROM Device;
```

**Oracle:**

```
SELECT DeviceDetails.Device.ICCID from DeviceDetails;
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, it fails with:

    Query has failed: near ">": syntax error

Comment: Added an Oracle option you can try

Comment: No go on that one either

Comment: What MDM is it?

Comment: SamsungSDS CellWe EMM

Comment: I found this so far, so we need a MSSQL 2012 query ----- The EMM Server includes the RSA Crypto-J 6.1 cryptographic module as part of
its software, and the EMM Server’s Microsoft Windows platform includes SQL server
2008-2012 and an EJBCA certificate authority.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft SQL Server:

If you are FORTUNATE enough to have SQL Server 2016 you can use new functionality MS has FINALLY put into SQL Server.

```
DECLARE @Device TABLE  ( value VARCHAR(4000))

INSERT INTO @Device (value) VALUES (
'{
    "BadgeNumber": 0,
    "DeviceLocale": "en-US",
    "ICCID": "0000000000000004720",
    "InstalledPoliciesSignedBy": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX1690F",
    "AvailableDeviceCapacity": 00000000080,
    "OSSdkVersion": 24,
    "ModemFirmwareVersion": "angler-03.72",
    "DeviceCapacity": 00000000184,
    "Product": "Nexus 6P/angler",
    "WiFiMAC": "02:00:00:00:00:00"
}')

SELECT      
    JSON_VALUE(value, '$.ICCID') as ICCID
FROM @Device
```

If not you may want to either roll your own CLR or take a look at what this author created here: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think it's MSSQL.